# Gridster.js grag and drop block to arbitrary position

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, gridster

I want to drag and drop blocks to arbitrary positions, for exampe allign blocks to the bottom of container, so there will be free space at the top. Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't use gridster use jquery sortable

Comment: I think it doesn't fit my needs. I want something like Android screen icons/widgets dragging and with ability of resize widgets. All except the subject already in gridster.